# Unable to toggle between two CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a dropbox menu for a project I'm working on. I've tried to follow this method down below, but I am running into issues.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

Below is my javascript code where it uses it adds an event listener to the button. **For context**, MenuView consists of a button, a div that contains two input fields, and an unordered list to view the menu items.

```
MenuView.prototype.initEvents = function() {
    console.log('initEvents MenuView');
    /* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    document.getElementById("dropbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('Showing menu');
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        console.log(document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList);
    }, false);


    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }   
}
```

The following is the output to the console when the button is pressed:

```
DOMTokenList(2) ["dropdown-content", "show", value: "dropdown-content show"]
```

**CSS**

```
/* Dropdown Button */
#dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
#dropbtn:hover, #dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
#menuView {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  z-index: 0;  
  position: sticky; /* Allocates space for the element, but moves it with you when you scroll */
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0; /* specifies the start position for the sticky behavior - 0 is pretty common */
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 200;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content div ul{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content div ul:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I've tried different combinations of my CSS and I have no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
In case some of you wanted a JFiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyzhuu/x8ad0nk2/3/

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you can provide a link with a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  of a reproducible part of your code.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be possible, I have several files that communicate with each other. Unless fiddle allows me to have multiple different files :(

Comment: `if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtn'))` is testing a String, while `event.target` is an Object. Also, I don't recommend testing a click on the entire `window`, unless it is necessary. Just attach the event to the desired node.

Comment: That's why I recommended a reproducible part of your code.

Comment: @StackSlave as per the documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches, the method accepts a string

Comment: @DiegoGallegos I have something similar here now, https://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyzhuu/x8ad0nk2/1/, if you remove the CSS it shows what's within the menuView div, but when you add it on, nothing shows up when you click the button

Comment: Updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/ze6x8ths/2/) (fixed typos)

Answer (score 0):

Working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/ze6x8ths/4/)

Changes:

- Comment out "addEventListener" (otherwise, the class toggle is triggered twice)
- Add ".dropbtn" class to the drop button (otherwise, the class is added, then immediately removed)

```js
function myFunction() {
    /* document.getElementById("dropBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { */
        console.log('Showing menu');
        document.getElementById("myDropDown").classList.toggle("show");
        //console.log(document.getElementById("myDropDown").classList);
    /* }, false); */
}


// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
#dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
#dropbtn:hover,
#dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
#menuView {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: sticky;
    /* Allocates space for the element, but moves it with you when you scroll */
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    /* specifies the start position for the sticky behavior - 0 is pretty common */
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 200;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content div {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content div:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <button id="btn-show-cart">Show Cart</button>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="menuView">
                <button id="dropBtn" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
                    Menu
                </button>
                <div id="myDropDown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <div>
                        Input
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        List
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="productView">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        <div id="modal" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <div id="modal-content">
            </div>
            <button id="btn-hide-cart">X
            </button>
        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That wasn't the output I was looking for :( I wanted everything within the "myDropdrop" div to be displayed.

Comment: @Jeff Could you clarify? I see both "Input" and "List" when I click on it.

Comment: oh sorry, the code was not loading properly when I clicked on the run code link here haha :P I do have a question, i kept everything as is, but I added the class name there.. why does that solve the issue though? Thanks :)

Comment: @Jeff If you don't add the class name "dropbtn" to the element, then the class gets added through the `#dropBtn` event listener, then the class gets removed in the `window` event listener. If still confused. add a `console.log` in the `window` event listener function.

Comment: Ahh, ok thank you so much! I have a follow up question if you don't mind answering :) Say for the div with id="myDropdown", if I were to put an input field instead of the text there, how would I prevent the window from closing before I get the input inside it?

Comment: Hey @Jeff, could you post a new question on StackOverflow? Then you could post a link here :)